# Common values between two columns in mysql table

Tags: sql

```
SELECT employee_id
     , first_name
     , last_name
  FROM Employees
 WHERE LOWER(SUBSTR(first_name, -1)) IN ('a','e','i','o','u')
   AND LOWER(SUBSTR(last_name, -1)) IN ('a','e','i','o','u');
```

*** I have taken column1 which ends with vowels then column2 ends with vowels. I need to take values from both columns which ends with same characters. Like ex if column1 has 'steven'  & column2 has 'shan'

Comment: Obviously `AND LOWER(SUBSTR(first_name, -1)) = LOWER(SUBSTR(last_name, -1))` instead of one of conditions.

Comment: Note that it's pretty unusual to find yourself using a case sensitive collation

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want both the conditions then you can use following query.

```
SELECT employee_id, first_name, last_name
FROM Employees
WHERE LOWER(SUBSTR(first_name, -1)) IN ('a','e','i','o','u') -- check for vowel
AND LOWER(SUBSTR(last_name, -1)) = LOWER(SUBSTR(first_name, -1)); -- check for same last character
```

Comment: Thanks Bro I have got the answer  SELECT employee_id, first_name, last_name
FROM Employees WHERE LOWER(SUBSTR(first_name, -1)) IN ('a','e','i','o','u')
AND LOWER(SUBSTR(last_name, -1)) IN ('a','e','i','o','u') and
LOWER(SUBSTR(last_name, -1))=lower(substr(first_name,-1));

Comment: @Siva One of first two conditions is excess - equiation is transitive.

Comment: @Siva as mentioned by Akina, you can remove one of the first two conditions.- as I did in my answer

Comment: Ok dude got it thnx

Comment: One last ques, I created a table as create table empty (product char(10)), then I modified it to alter table empty modify product varchar(10) it gives me  the output but when I again modified to alter table empty modify product varchar(6) it gives me error like data truncated for column at row1

Comment: It may be because you have the data in the product column with more than 6 length.

Comment: You can accept this answer if it resolved your issue.

Comment: Bro how to convert multiple rows into a single row in mysql workbench

Comment: @Siva actually, you should ask another question for it. And accept this answer as it resolved your question.